# I can try create login page but getting error on state email

Tags: android, react-native

```
  import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    SafeAreaView,
    Text,
    View,
    Image,
    ScrollView,
    StyleSheet,
    StatusBar,
    TextInput,
    TouchableOpacity

} from 'react-native';


export default class LoginFrom extends React. Component {
    state = {
        isLoading: false,
        strEmail: "test@example.com", isEmailValid: true, errMsgEmail: "",
        strPassword: "test@123", isPasswordValid: true, errMsgPassword: "",
        strErrMsg: ""
    }


    login() {
        setTimeout(() => {

            fetch("url", {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    'email': this.state.strEmail,
                    'password': this.state.strPassword
                })
            }).then((response) => {
                if (response.status == 200) {
                    return response.json()
                } else {
                    return null
                }
            }).then((responseJson) => {
                console.log(responseJson);

                if (responseJson != null) {
                    this.setState({
                        strErrMsg: ""
                    })


                } else {
                    this.setState({
                        strErrMsg: "Email and password does not match."
                    })
                }
            })

        }, 100);

    }
    txtEmailChangeHangler = (val) => {
        this.setState({
            strEmail: val.trim()
        })
    }

    txtPasswordChangeHangler = (val) => {
        this.setState({
            strPassword: val.trim()
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <TextInput style={styles.inputbox}
                    onSubmitEditing={() => { this.secondTextInput.focus(); }}
                    underlineColorAndroid='rgba(0,0,0,0)'
                    placeholder='Email'
                    selectionColor='#fff'
                    value={this.state.strEmail}
                    onChangeText={this.txtEmailChangeHangler}
                    keyboardType='email-address' />
                <TextInput
                    secureTextEntry={true}
                    style={styles.inputbox}
                    underlineColorAndroid='rgba(0,0,0,0)'
                    placeholder='password'
                    onChangeText={this.txtPasswordChangeHangler}
                    value={this.state.strPassword}
                    ref={(input) => { this.secondTextInput = input; }} />

                <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.login} style={styles.button}>
                    <Text style={styles.buttontext}>{this.props.type}</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        );

    }

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        backgroundColor: '#D3EDFA',
        flexGrow: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center'


    },
    inputbox: {
        width: 300,
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,1)',
        borderRadius: 25,
        paddingHorizontal: 16,
        marginVertical: 10

    },
    button: {
        width: 300,
        backgroundColor: '#ED6825',
        borderRadius: 25,
        paddingVertical: 16,
        marginVertical: 10

    },
    buttontext:
    {
        fontSize: 16,
        color: '#ffffff',
        fontWeight: '100',
        textAlign: 'center',
        paddingHorizontal: 16,

    }




})
```

Comment: Hi Raju it would be great if you will explain it properly, please go through the guidelines for posting questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try replacing login function with fat arrow function

```
login() {
       // your code here
    }
```

to

```
login = () => {
    // your code here
    }
```

hope it helps, this is done because fat arrow functions implicty binds `this` keyword